# Installing a LaTeX template that has only .tex files

Tags: installing, templates

I downloaded the Legrand Orange Book template from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book , but I can't figure out how to actually install/use it.  When I downloaded `memoir`, it had an installer that automatically put the files where they need to go, so all I needed to do was `\documentclass{memoir}`

For the Legrand template, I've created a personal directory structure `texmf`, but putting in the two `.tex` files from the Legrand template doesn't seem to do anything. How do I use the template?  I use Scrivener to write my document (it has MMD3), so `memoir` works very well.  I just want to use the Legrand Orange Book.

I'm running `TeXShop` installed as part of `MacTex` distribution.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your personal `texmf` tree must mimic the actual TDS.  That means, for LaTeX related material, you should put the files in `~/texmf/tex/latex/legrand` (though of course the `legrand` sub-dir is not strictly necessary).  Search for questions on 'personal texmf' on this site for further details; Macs have a slightly different base structure involving a `Library` folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a template, not a class so you do not have to install anything. Just open the file `main.tex` and modify the content (between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) as you want. Follow the comment instructions of the author of the template.

In the `structure.tex` there are the main settings of the template. If you want you can try to look at it and modify something but at beginning simply leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put a copy of the to `.tex` files in the working directory of your current project.
And keep the original version elsewhere (e.g. in your personal `texmf`) for the future.